# Generate POCOs from an existing database EF 5 (with some conditions)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

I have an existing database that I want to generate its POCOs but **I want to end up with model classes outside `.tt` file, without giving `partial` definition and "auto generated" comment header for each class** I want to have a result like I started building POCOs from scratch. Is there a process to get this result ? Regards

I want to regenerate my database and start updating model from POCOs using migrations

**Update** : After editing Template File (.tt) I could remove the header comment and partial definition. I think I could get my work done manually. Now, I just need to Exclude `.tt` file and its sub classes from project and then add only my business classes to the project again.

Comment: Have you tried DbContext Generator template with Update Model from Database?

Comment: Yes, and it generates all this things I don't want to get : .tt file, partial class etc.. very annoying

Comment: You can't generate anything without generator itself. POCO generator is .tt files. Why don't you want them? Also why don't you want partial classes? This gives a brilliant possibility to extend each particular entity type by your own desire, if you don't want - just don't touch, this doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Extending classes decreases code readability, and gives additional complexity to my current code. there are many classes to reimplement and a lot of functions to add

Comment: If a class being generated basing a template what other way to extend it do you see?

Comment: Note, if you remove .tt then you're loosing a possibility to update previously generated classes and generate new.

Comment: Yes, I really want to start from scratch even by deleting the current database, once I get my POCOs ready

Comment: POCO will not create a new database for you, you'll get a mapping exception instead.

Comment: @abatishchev Thanks for your time, I got my database generated like a charm by following steps I mentioned above and finally changing the connection string in App.config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 3](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) extension to generate your pocos. It has an option to reverse Engineer Code First which Generates POCO classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing database.

Comment: +1. That's what I use, I generally design the database 'by hand' and let the Power Tools do the mapping when using EF. As a side note to whomever might be looking, [NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=nmg) is an equivalent for (Fluent) NHibernate mappings.

Comment: +1 it's taking me half way. but it still doesn't give me what I need

Comment: @HichemC What more do you need? You just have to add migrations and you're done.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor: I'd recommend SQL Server Project (.sqlproj) to design and source control your database scheme.

Comment: @abatishchev Thanks, I'll definitely check that out :)